# How to implement Multi-type IComparable / IEquatable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, icomparable, iequatable

Let say I have the following class:

```
public sealed class ScaleValue : 
    IComparable, IComparable<ScaleValue>, IEquatable<ScaleValue>
{
    public double Value
    { get; set;}
    public string Definition
    { get; set;}

    // interface methods
    ...
}
```

If I want to make my class comparable to a `double` should I just include `IComparable<double>` and implement it that way or do I have to do it another way?

And when I want my class to be comparable to doubles should the `double.CompareTo` give the same result as the `ScaleValue.CompareTo`?

and how about `Equals`?

I think I put the responsibilities wrong in my design.
I think my best option is to make a Scale class with a `ContainsValue(double Value)` method.
This way I can look up the value and keep the responsibilities where they are needed.

Comment: The problem here is that comparable check will no longer be symmetric.    someScaleValue.CompareTo(1.2) will return a value, but `1.2.CompareTo(someScaleValue)` will throw an exception, because the `double` version of comparability won't know how to handle your type.  That's...a problem.

Comment: You already have a double there, just compare that (remember the KISS principle)

Comment: Why would you want your class to be comparable to doubles? Are you trying to make a static method? You already have IComparable<ScaleValue> implemented. In the Comparer method, you can compare the ScaleValue.Value member..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your class is comparable to is up to you.  You could make it comparable to *anything*, as the non-generic version of the [`IComparable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) takes an `object`; in the implementation of [`CompareTo` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx), you can basically sniff the type of the object (unless it is `null`).

When you use the generic version of [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx), you're making the statement that you implement a strongly-typed comparison method to whatever the type parameter `T` is.

Generally, if you have an `IComparable<T>` implementation for one type, you *probably* should have an `IEquatable<T>` implementation as well.

Having an `IComparable/IComparable<T>` implementation means that what is being represented by the structure has a natural ordering to it.  Ordering also implies that there can be equality between two instances: if instance `a` of `T` is not greater than or less than instance `b` of `T` then it *must* be equal.

To that end, if you implement `IComparable/IComparable<T>`, then logic dictates that you implement `IEquatable/IEquatable<T>`.

Of course, when you implement `IEquatable/IEquatable<T>`, you should override [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) and [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx).

Which in turn means that you should override all the comparison operators:

- `==` (which implies `!=`)
- `<` and `<=`
- `>` and `>=`

Comment: what you told me i already figured out. what my point is that i have a set of ScaleValue's name `Scale`. now i want to check if some value `a` of the type `double` is in the list. `Scale.contains(a)`. that is why i asked if i should implement `Icomparable<double>`. in the ScaleValue class the definition propertie is less important.

Comment: @user2038134 That makes no sense.  What if you have two properties that expose `double`?  One implementation of `IComparable<double>` wouldn't give you what you're looking for.  You need to use something like the `Where` extension method in LINQ to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare objects in a collection to an object of different type using contains method unless you implement a whole new collection type for your class or using some sort of extension method!!!